# RSS feed accessing <a> elements

Tags: php, xml, twig, simplexml

I need help with displaying content from this XML block:

```
<content type="xhtml">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <p>We are excited to announce that the <a href="https://world.phparch.com/call-for-speakers/">Call for Speakers</a> has opened for <a href="https://world.phparch.com">php[world] 2016</a>.
 </p>
 <p>Now in its 3rd year, <a href="https://world.phparch.com">php[world]</a> is the conference designed to bring the entire world of PHP together in one place, with dedicated tracks for the biggest applications and frameworks in the PHP community such as WordPress, Drupal, Magento, Joomla!, Symfony, Zend Framework, CakePHP, and Laravel.
 </p>
 <p>We need to hear from you what you want to speak about though.  Talks that fit any of those frameworks or are related to PHP development are all welcome.  We offer a comprehensive speakers package to make sure that our presenters aren't put out financially for the event, including:
 </p>
 <ul>
 <li>Airfare coverage ($400 domestic, $1000 international)</li>
 <li>Hotel room (1 night + 1 per accepted talk)</li>
 <li>Free ticket to the conference</li>
 <li>Most meals included!</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Don't hesitate, our <a href="https://world.phparch.com/call-for-speakers/">Call for Speakers</a> is only open for 3 weeks and closes on June 24th, 2016.  So get those submissions in soon, we look forward to <a href="https://world.phparch.com/call-for-speakers/">hearing from you</a>!</p>
</div>
```

I can' t display a element inside p XML element,
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although all the children of the root div have no prefix, they are in a namespace, which specifies its attributes. Therefore, you can not refer to them in the usual way

With DomDocument the code maybe:

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->loadXML($string); 
$xp = new DomXpath($xml);
$xp->registerNamespace('o', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

foreach($xp->query('//o:p/o:a') as $a) 
     echo $a->nodeValue . "\n";
```

[demo](https://eval.in/583320)

or with SimpleXML so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('o', "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
foreach($xml->xpath('//o:p/o:a') as $a) 
     echo $a . "\n";
```

[demo](https://eval.in/583322)

Comment: Yes thank u it works, do u know how to get  also href element from this <a> ?

Comment: with simplexml : `echo $a['href'] . "\n";`